# How to configure Azure AD redirect url when publishing app to local web server?

Tags: c#, azure, redirect, authentication

I have developed a VS2017 app. using Azure AD login. It is presently on my desktop. The app is registered with Microsoft, and the login process successfully redirects from Microsoft to our local authentication server login page. After login the app then successfully redirects to my localhost dev environment and the app works fine. My question? I now need to configure on a local server for testing. The redirect URL still points to localhost. What do I need to do to get the app working in terms of configuring redirects?

Comment: "The redirect URL still points to localhost." Do you mean the Redirect URL in your code or the Redirect URL on the Azure AD Application?

Comment: @Phil, thank you for your reply. have fixed it. Simply had to set the return url in the Microsoft app portal for the app, to match that in web.config.

Comment: That would have been my advice extactly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply had to set the return url in the Microsoft app portal for the app, to match that in web.config.